# How do I associate an OpenID with an unregistered account?

Tags: support, openid, user-accounts

I started posting questions to SO using an "unregistered" account some months ago. (Very convenient, by the way.) Now I want to register and establish a more permanent account. Trouble is, I cannot find a way to add a login/pass or OpenID to the account. When I go to the user page (https://stackoverflow.com/users/182237) and click on Register, and then log in through Google, it creates a *new* account rather than associating the OpenID with my existing (unregistered) one. Am I just stuck?

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is send an e-mail to team@stackoverflow.com (linked to at the bottom of every page) and supply the ID or user page URLs of the two accounts. They can then merge the accounts for you.

Comment: Thanks Michael - I had accidentally created an unregistered account on one site and it was bugging me that I couldn't figure out a way to merge.